# Uintended behavior - Getting a duplicate in the "join on" field, in a FULL OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am joining four views to display A/R, sales, deposits, etc on ReportingMonth.  But I'm getting duplicates on some months.  Look towards the bottom, in particular Jan 2014, Feb 2014, Dec 2012.

[image: duplicate months]

What I have:

```
SELECT ISNULL(ISNULL(ISNULL(outf.ReportingMonth, sales.ReportingMonth), dep.ReportingMonth), ar.ReportingMonth) AS ReportingMonth
    ,ar.AR_100_Percent AS EndOfMonthARBalance
    ,ar.AR_85_Percent AS MLOCCeiling
    ,sales.MonthlySales AS Sales
    ,dep.Deposits
    ,outf.Outflow
    ,dep.Deposits + outf.Outflow AS CashPerformance
FROM vCI_MLOC_MONTHLYAR ar
FULL OUTER JOIN vCI_MLOC_MONTHLYSALES sales
ON ar.ReportingMonth = sales.ReportingMonth
FULL OUTER JOIN vCI_MLOC_MONTHLYDEPOSITS dep
ON sales.ReportingMonth = dep.ReportingMonth
FULL OUTER JOIN vCI_MLOC_MONTHLYOUTF outf
ON dep.ReportingMonth = outf.ReportingMonth
GROUP BY outf.ReportingMonth
    ,dep.ReportingMonth
    ,ar.ReportingMonth
    ,sales.ReportingMonth
    ,ar.AR_100_Percent
    ,ar.AR_85_Percent
    ,sales.MonthlySales
    ,dep.Deposits
    ,outf.Outflow
```

Comment: I think you might not actually want a "full outer" join here. This is not a "duplicate", it's exactly what the query asked for.

Comment: What kind of join is appropriate here?  I have four views, each with disparate reporting months.  Reporting Months are not always perfect match (nulls here and there).

Comment: I think the solution Gordon Linoff provided is the way to go!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem when doing `full outer joins`, because you end up with missing data in the key columns.

The the following version uses a driver table to get all the months, and does all the joins to that table:

```
SELECT driver.ReportingMonth
    ,(other fields here)
FROM (select distinct ReportingMonth
      from ((select ReportingMonth
             from vCI_MLOC_MONTHLYAR
            ) union all
            (select ReportingMonth
             from vCI_MLOC_MONTHLYSALES
            ) union all
            (select ReportingMonth
             from vCI_MLOC_MONTHLYDEPOSITS
            ) union all
            (select ReportingMonth
             from vCI_MLOC_MONTHLYOUTF
            )
           ) t
     ) driver
FULL OUTER JOIN vCI_MLOC_MONTHLYAR ar on driver.ReportingMonth = ar.ReportingMonth
FULL OUTER JOIN vCI_MLOC_MONTHLYSALES sales
ON driver.ReportingMonth = sales.ReportingMonth
FULL OUTER JOIN vCI_MLOC_MONTHLYDEPOSITS dep
ON driver.ReportingMonth = dep.ReportingMonth
FULL OUTER JOIN vCI_MLOC_MONTHLYOUTF outf
ON driver.ReportingMonth = outf.ReportingMonth
```

Comment: I think you might be onto something!  I am having trouble selecting the needed fields from your query (AR, Sales, Dep, Outf, etc.).  Can you specify what should go before the FROM in line one?

Answer (score 1):

Joining 4 tables (or views, that doesn't matter) with `FULL` joins is tricky. On the second and third join, some of the columns you are trying to join on, may be `NULL` (due to the first or second outer join).

Here's what might solve the issue. Replace the `FROM` clause with:

```
FROM vCI_MLOC_MONTHLYAR ar
  FULL OUTER JOIN vCI_MLOC_MONTHLYSALES sales
    ON ar.ReportingMonth = sales.ReportingMonth
  FULL OUTER JOIN vCI_MLOC_MONTHLYDEPOSITS dep
    ON COALESCE(ar.ReportingMonth, sales.ReportingMonth) 
       = dep.ReportingMonth
  FULL OUTER JOIN vCI_MLOC_MONTHLYOUTF outf
    ON COALESCE(ar.ReportingMonth, sales.ReportingMonth, dep.ReportingMonth) 
       = outf.ReportingMonth
```

or with:

```
FROM 
        vCI_MLOC_MONTHLYAR ar
      FULL OUTER JOIN vCI_MLOC_MONTHLYSALES sales
          ON ar.ReportingMonth = sales.ReportingMonth
  FULL OUTER JOIN 
        vCI_MLOC_MONTHLYDEPOSITS dep
      FULL OUTER JOIN vCI_MLOC_MONTHLYOUTF outf
          ON dep.ReportingMonth = outf.ReportingMonth
    ON COALESCE(ar.ReportingMonth, sales.ReportingMonth)
     = COALESCE(dep.ReportingMonth, out.ReportingMonth)
```

---

The other solution would be to have a `calendar` table with a `ReportingMonth` column or if there isn't one, to create it on the fly (similar to @Gordon's solution):

```
SELECT cal.ReportingMonth
       --- all the other columns do not change
FROM 
    ( SELECT ReportingMonth
      FROM vCI_MLOC_MONTHLYAR ar
    UNION 
      SELECT ReportingMonth
      FROM vCI_MLOC_MONTHLYSALES sales
    UNION 
      SELECT ReportingMonth
      FROM vCI_MLOC_MONTHLYDEPOSITS dep
    UNION 
      SELECT ReportingMonth
      FROM vCI_MLOC_MONTHLYOUTF outf
    ) AS cal
LEFT JOIN
    vCI_MLOC_MONTHLYAR ar
        ON ar   .ReportingMonth = cal.ReportingMonth
LEFT JOIN
    vCI_MLOC_MONTHLYSALES sales
        ON sales.ReportingMonth = cal.ReportingMonth
LEFT JOIN
    vCI_MLOC_MONTHLYDEPOSITS dep
        ON dep  .ReportingMonth = cal.ReportingMonth
LEFT JOIN
    vCI_MLOC_MONTHLYOUTF outf
        ON outf .ReportingMonth = cal.ReportingMonth
```

Answer (score 1):

This works too...

```
SELECT ReportingMonth
    ,SUM(EndOfMonthARBalance) AS EndOfMonthARBalance
    ,SUM(MLOCCeiling) AS MLOCCeiling
    ,SUM(Sales) AS Sales
    ,SUM(Deposits) AS Deposits
    ,SUM(Outflow) AS Outflow
    ,SUM(Deposits) + SUM(Outflow) AS CashPerformance

FROM(
    SELECT ReportingMonth AS ReportingMonth
         , NULL AS EndOfMonthARBalance
         , NULL AS MLOCCeiling
         , NULL AS Sales
         , NULL AS Deposits
         , Outflow AS Outflow
    FROM vCI_MLOC_MONTHLYOUTF

    UNION ALL
    SELECT ReportingMonth AS ReportingMonth
         , NULL AS EndOfMonthARBalance
         , NULL AS MLOCCeiling
         , MonthlySales AS Sales
         , NULL AS Deposits
         , NULL AS Outflow
    FROM vCI_MLOC_MONTHLYSALES

    UNION ALL
    SELECT ReportingMonth AS ReportingMonth
         , NULL AS EndOfMonthARBalance
         , NULL AS MLOCCeiling
         , NULL AS Sales
         , Deposits AS Deposits
         , NULL AS Outflow
    FROM vCI_MLOC_MONTHLYDEPOSITS

    UNION ALL  
    SELECT ReportingMonth AS ReportingMonth
         , AR_100_Percent AS EndOfMonthARBalance
         , AR_85_Percent AS MLOCCeiling
         , NULL AS Sales
         , NULL AS Deposits
         , NULL AS Outflow
    FROM vCI_MLOC_MONTHLYAR
) AS a    
GROUP BY ReportingMonth
```